# Recyclerview Swipes + CardView Touch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, onitemclicklistener

Below you can see working app with some issues with swipes on Recyclerview with CardView
[image]

As you can see, I need catch LEFT/RIGHT swipes on the whole Recyclerview and Click event on the Recyclerview Card item. Swipes work good without items in my Recyclerview, but when Recyclerview contains items, each swipe prevented by Click event on Card item. **How to make it right way, so I can swipe LEFT/RIGHT on the whole Recyclerview and also Click on Card item?**

This is layout code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/workout_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.mikesu.horizontalexpcalendar.HorizontalExpCalendar
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    exp:center_container_expanded_height="318dp" />
```

Activity code

```
workoutListAdapter = new WorkoutListAdapter(workoutList, this, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rvActivities.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvActivities.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvActivities.setAdapter(workoutListAdapter);
    rvActivities.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    rvActivities.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            DateTime dateTime = selectedDate.plusDays(1);
            calendar.scrollToDate(dateTime, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            DateTime dateTime = selectedDate.minusDays(1);
            calendar.scrollToDate(dateTime, true);
        }
    });
```

And OnSwipeTouchListener code

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 300;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

}

And on the future I need also add contextmenu on Card item, would it be same problem like Click event, which will prevent swipe actions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my solution

OnSwipeTouchListener class

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        onItemTouch(e.getX(), e.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        onItemLongTouch(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                } else {
                    onItemTouch(e2.getX(), e2.getY());
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}

public void onItemTouch(float x, float y) {
}

public void onItemTouch() {
}

public void onItemLongTouch(float x, float y) {
}

public void onItemLongTouch() {
}
```

}

And in my activity

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            DateTime dateTime = selectedDate.plusDays(1);
            calendar.scrollToDate(dateTime, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            DateTime dateTime = selectedDate.minusDays(1);
            calendar.scrollToDate(dateTime, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemTouch(float x, float y) {
            View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
            if (view != null && view.getTag() != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);  
                // getting clicked item position and passing Object key to new activity
                intent.putExtra("recyclerview_item_position", mData.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getKey());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongTouch(float x, float y) {
            View view = rvActivities.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
            if (view != null && view.getTag() != null) {
                Log.d("log", "Long Touch");
            }
        }
    });
```

**And one more thing: in Recyclerview Adapter in onCreateViewHolder method set TAG to current position of inflated view.**

Comment: After I perform swipe right\left (I move the view), the on click and on long click stop to react and it thinks i always perform swipe, If i just touch the view it moves a bit to the left\right, is there a way to refresh the action every time the user lifts his finger from the view?